# How create a collapse table with jQuery Ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to create a website where I can search for a specific product with the cheapest vendors. I'm able to fetch the data from the database with Elastichsearch and get the database with jQuery Ajax.

```
<script>
    $('.js-ajax').select2({
        ajax: {
            url: '/product/api/elasticsearch',
            dataType: 'json',
            width: 'resolve', // need to override the changed default
            minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
            dropdownCssClass: 'select2-hidden',

            success: function (data) {
                var returnedData = data;
                // clear table
                $('#products tbody').empty();

                for(let i = 0; i < returnedData.results.length; i++){
                    $("#products").find('tbody')
                        .append($('<tr>')
                            .append($('<td>')
                                .text(returnedData.results[i].id)
                            )

                            .append($('<td class="columt">')
                                .text(returnedData.results[i].text)
                            )

                            .mouseover(returnedData.results[1].text)

                            .append($('<td class="columnp">')
                                .text(returnedData.results[i].sku)
                            )
                            .append($('<td class="colum7">')
                                .text(returnedData.results[i].vendor)
                            )
                        );
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I'm able to put the response in a table but how can I put the response into a collapse table? I think that I have to create a foreach loop and tag every products.

I tried this but it's not working

```
function addProducts(products) {
  products.forEach(fucntion(product) {
                   var template = $('#products').text();//get template
                    template = template.replace('{id}', product.id);//replace placeholders to data
                    template = template.replace('{title}', product.title);
                    template = template.replace('{price}', product.id);
                    //...other data
                    $('#search-result').append(template);//add to box
                    bindProduct(product.id);//add event  
                   });
}

function bindProduct(productID) {
  $('#'+productID).on('mouseover', function() {//or another event
    showPopup();//justs add opened class or what you want
  });
}
```

There was a syntax error on the above code which I was not able to find.

The first idea was to put the data in table with mouseover. But since this will not work as expected on a small screen I decided to put the data in collapse but i'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

you misspelled function as fucntion.
try:

```
function addProducts(products) {
  products.forEach(function(product) { //here was the "fuction" misspell
                   var template = $('#products').text();//get template
                    template = template.replace('{id}', product.id);//replace placeholders to data
                    template = template.replace('{title}', product.title);
                    template = template.replace('{price}', product.id);
                    //...other data
                    $('#search-result').append(template);//add to box
                    bindProduct(product.id);//add event  
                   });
}

function bindProduct(productID) {
  $('#'+productID).on('mouseover', function() {//or another event
    showPopup();//justs add opened class or what you want
  });
}
```

Comment: Thx for the update, is it also to replace the mouseover event into a collapse with this code snippet?